# Javascript - isNaN and parseInt

Tags: javascript

I have a simple counter function but the isNaN function is not working well. What I'm trying to do is that when I remove the number inside the input number box and then click the incrementor or decrementor, the number is supposed to return 0 but nothing. How can I make the value keeps returning a 0 when the value is not a number? Any idea?

```js
function inc(element) {
let el = document.querySelector(`[name="${element}"]`);

if (isNaN(el.value)) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return el.value = parseInt(el.value) + 1;
}
}

function dec(element) {
let el = document.querySelector(`[name="${element}"]`);
if (isNaN(el.value)) {
    return 0;
} else {
    if (parseInt(el.value) > 0) {
        el.value = parseInt(el.value) - 1;
    }
}
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* reset */
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type="number"]:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]:hover::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

/* qty input */
.input-number-button {
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid var(--Grey2)
}

.input-number-button input[type="number"] {
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 10px;
}

.input-number-button input[type="number"]:focus,
.input-number-button button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.input-number-button button {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    font-size: 25px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: var(--mainWhite);
}

.input-number-button .input-arrow-down,
.input-number-button .input-arrow-up {
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.input-number-button .input-arrow-up  {
    background-color: orangered;
}

.input-number-button .input-arrow-down {
    background-color: olivedrab;
}

.input-number-button span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-number-button">
        <button class="input-arrow-down" onclick="dec('qty')">
            <span>-</span>
        </button>
        <input class="input-number-box" type="number" name="qty" min="1" max="20" value="0" />
        <button class="input-arrow-up" onclick="inc('qty')">
            <span>+</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you mean `el.value = 0` (or rather `el.value = '0'`) instead of `el.value === 0`?

Comment: 0 is supposed to be a number.

Comment: Sure, but `el.value` is always a string, that's why you're parsing it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, when you enter a non numeric number, e.value is "". maybe you can try this

```js
function inc(element) {
  const el = document.querySelector(`[name="${element}"]`);
  const val = (el.value) ? parseInt(el.value, 10) + 1 : 0;
  el.value = Math.min(val, parseInt(el.getAttribute("max"), 10));
}

function dec(element) {
  const el = document.querySelector(`[name="${element}"]`);
  const val = (el.value) ? parseInt(el.value, 10) - 1 : 0;
  el.value = Math.max(parseInt(el.getAttribute("min"), 10), val);
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* reset */
input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type="number"]:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]:hover::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* qty input */
.input-number-button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid var(--Grey2)
}

.input-number-button input[type="number"] {
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
}

.input-number-button input[type="number"]:focus,
.input-number-button button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.input-number-button button {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--mainWhite);
}

.input-number-button .input-arrow-down,
.input-number-button .input-arrow-up {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-number-button .input-arrow-up {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.input-number-button .input-arrow-down {
  background-color: olivedrab;
}

.input-number-button span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-number-button">
  <button class="input-arrow-down" onclick="dec('qty')">
    <span>-</span>
  </button>
  <input class="input-number-box" type="number" name="qty" min="1" max="20" value="0" />
  <button class="input-arrow-up" onclick="inc('qty')">
    <span>+</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also optimize your solution like below. :-)

```js
function incDec(element, type) {
    let el = document.querySelector(`[name="${element}"]`);
    let data = '';
    if (type === 'inc') {
      data = !el.value && !isNaN(el.value) ? 0 : parseInt(el.value) + 1;
    } else {
      data = !el.value && !isNaN(el.value) ? 0 : parseInt(el.value) - 1;
    }
    el.value = data;
  }
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* reset */
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type="number"]:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]:hover::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

/* qty input */
.input-number-button {
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid var(--Grey2)
}

.input-number-button input[type="number"] {
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 10px;
}

.input-number-button input[type="number"]:focus,
.input-number-button button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.input-number-button button {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    font-size: 25px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: var(--mainWhite);
}

.input-number-button .input-arrow-down,
.input-number-button .input-arrow-up {
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.input-number-button .input-arrow-up  {
    background-color: orangered;
}

.input-number-button .input-arrow-down {
    background-color: olivedrab;
}

.input-number-button span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-number-button">
  <button class="input-arrow-down" onclick="incDec('qty', 'dec')">
    <span>-</span>
  </button>
  <input
    class="input-number-box"
    type="number"
    name="qty"
    min="1"
    max="20"
    value="0"
  />
  <button class="input-arrow-up" onclick="incDec('qty', 'inc')">
    <span>+</span>
  </button>
</div>
```